# Evaluate: $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{[0,\infty)} (1+x/n)^{-n}\sin(x/n)\,dx.$

Tags: limits, measure-theory

> Evaluate:$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^{\infty} \left(1+\frac xn\right)^{-n}\sin \frac xn\,dx.$$

I have tried to use the *(Lebesgue) dominated convergence theorem* to evaluate the same. At first I noticed that:

$\left|\left(1+\frac xn\right)^{-n}\sin \frac xn\right|\le\left|\left(1+\frac xn\right)^{-n}\right|\le1\text{ for all positive }x \text{ and for all natural }n\tag*{}.$

Since $g(x)=1$ is Lebesgue integrable for each $x\in[0,\infty).$ So by DCT, the given limit equals:
$$\int_0^{\infty} \lim_{n\to\infty}  \left(1+\frac xn\right)^{-n}\sin \frac xn\,dx=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x}\cdot0\,dx=0.$$

This question was asked in our end term exam this semester and so I don't know the correct answer to this question. Therefore, just to check whether I have evaluated the limit correctly I am posting the same here on MSE. If I have gone wrong somewhere, please point out and give some insights. Thanks in advance.

Comment: $g(x) = 1$ is not integrable on $(0,\infty)$ because $\int_0^\infty dx = \infty$.

Comment: “Since $g(x)=1$ is Lebesgue integrable for each $x\in[0,\infty)$” is really not clear. What may be qualified as integrable is a **function**. Besides, $\int_0^\infty 1\,\mathrm dx=\infty$…

Comment: Ah...  Yes yes I have totally missed the fact which both of you have pointed out.  Thanking you both.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: Using
$$ (1+z)^n\ge 1+\binom{n}{2}z^2 $$
for $z>0$, one has
$$ (1+\frac{x}{n})^n\ge1+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\frac{x^2}{n^2}=1+\frac12(1-\frac1n)x^2\ge1+\frac14x^2$$
for $n\ge2$. Then define
$$ f_n(x)=(1+\frac{x}{n})^{-n}\sin(\frac{x}{n}) $$
to estimate $f_n$ as
$$ |f_n(x)|\le\frac{4}{4+x^2} $$
for $x\ge1$ and then one can use LDC.

Comment: Thanks.. Got it. Then in $[0,1], g(x)=1$ and in $(1,\infty), g(x)=\frac4{x^2+4}.$ But the limit will still be $0.$ Isn't it, sir?

Comment: Yes, you are right. But $g(x)=\frac{4}{4+x^2}$ in $[1,\infty)$ is a little bit better.

Comment: Understood but sir I have one more query: What exactly led you to figure out the dominant integrable function $g(x)=\frac4{4+x^2}$ in $[1,\infty).$ I mean during the exam it took quite some time for me to figure out the dominant integrable function $g(x)=1$ itself in $[0,\infty).$ But then I totally missed (don't know why!) the fact that $1\not\in L^1([0,\infty)).$ So I just want to know is there anything (that I am not realizing), in the integrand, which make it kind of obvious to see what the dominant integrable function could be?

Comment: For the form of $(1+ax)^{-n}$, people use often use the Binomial Theorem to handle.

Comment: Sir, is $x\ge1$ really necessary for $|f_n(x)|\le\frac4{4+x^2}$ to hold true? For any $x$ in $[0,1),$ the validity of the aforementioned inequality depends on the value of $n(\ge2)$ and I am not able to find any such $n$ for which the inequality fails to hold. (Sorry if I am missing something obvious again!)

Answer (score 3):

Here is another approach in case you didn't think to use the inequality provided by @xpaul. With $x \rightarrow x/n$ we see $$\int_0^{\infty}(1+x/n)^{-n}\sin(x/n)\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{n\sin(x)}{(x+1)^n}\mathrm{d}x$$ Call this integral $a_n$. Verify yourself using $-1 \leq \sin(x) \leq 1$ that $|a_n|\leq 2$ for all $n>1$. Integrating by parts twice yields for $n>3$ $$a_n=\frac{n}{(n-1)(n-2)}\Bigg[1-\frac{a_{n-2}}{n-2}\Bigg]$$ Since $|a_{n-2}|\leq 2$ we have $$\frac{n}{(n-1)(n-2)}\Bigg[1-\frac{2}{n-2}\Bigg]\leq a_n\leq \frac{n}{(n-1)(n-2)}\Bigg[1+\frac{2}{n-2}\Bigg]$$ for all $n>3$. By the squeeze thereom $\{a_n\}_{n=2}^{\infty} \longrightarrow 0.$

Comment: Thank you sir for taking time to write this answer. Actually I did try to make use of the sandwich theorem but couldn't think of the substitution that you made in the beginning. In short my attempt wasn't that effective, sir.

Comment: You don't have to perform this substitution to get this relation between $a_{n-2}$ and $a_n$. I only did this to make the integral easier to handle. Using by parts on the original integral will get you the same result.

Comment: Actually sir I didn't perform integration by parts. I just had the following inequality: $0\le\int_{[0,\infty)} |f_n(x)|\,dx\le\int_{[0,\infty)}\frac{2n}{3n-1}x^{-2}\,dx,$ in hand. But the integral on the right diverges to $\infty.$ So this is of no use. Anyways next time if I encounter such a problem I'd definitely consider integration by parts as well.